# A solution for grouping items in loop with Timber and Twig

Tags: twig, timber

Often i need to do some tricky layout on dynamic elements like galleries.
Here's one example:

```
<ul>
<li class="slide">
    <img src="img_01.jpg">
    <img src="img_02.jpg">
</li>
<li class="slide">
    <img src="img_03.jpg">
    <img src="img_04.jpg">
</li>
<li class="slide">
    <img src="img_05.jpg">
    <img src="img_06.jpg">
</li>
</ul>
```

I've managed to do it with the following snippet. But i wanted some suggestions if possible about how to make it more flexible or more simple, like grouping by any number. Maybe using cycle() or any other method. I was getting strange results using the slice() or array[1:2] notation.

```
<ul>
{% for image in gallery %}
{% set current = loop.index %}
{% set next = current + 1 %}
    {% if current is odd %}
        <li class="slide">
            {% for image in gallery %}
                {% if loop.index in [current,next] %}
                {% set th = TimberImage(image) %}
                    <img src="{{th.src}}">
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Any suggestions are welcomed.
Timber becomes very handy for quick in and out fixes with Timber::compile or custom themes with full routing. The purpose of the question is to create some snippet that can be reused.

Kudos to creators.
https://github.com/timber/timber

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can approach with the `rest of the division` with the following code ([Here](http://twigfiddle.com/nvcfqn/2) a working solutions):

```
{# number of element for every section #}
{% set section = 2%}

<ul>
{% for image in gallery %}
   {% if loop.index % section == 1  %}
     <li class="slide">
   {% endif %}
   {% set th = TimberImage(image) %}
       <img src="{{th.src}}">
   {% if loop.index % section == 0 or loop.last %}
     </li>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

You can easily reuse this code making a [Twig macro](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html#macro) using as parameter the gallery and the number of element for section (highlighted with the variable `section`

Comment: Great solution! Thanks a lot for taking your time to answer. Definitively more concise and reusable.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the final result taking the suggestion of @Matteo for a macro:
https://gist.github.com/lithiumlab/5ee0454b0a77b1cc26fc0ce8ba52fd80

views/single.twig:

```
{% import 'utils.twig' as utils %}
{{utils.group_collection(gallery,3)}}
```

views/utils.twig:

```
{% macro group_collection(collection, groupby) %}
{% set section = groupby|default(2) %}

    <ul>
    {% for element in collection %}
       {% if loop.index % section == 1  %}
         <li class="group">
       {% endif %}
       {% set th = TimberImage(element) %}
           <img src="{{th.src}}">
       {% if loop.index % section == 0 or loop.last %}
         </li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% endmacro %}
```